# How to Filter by Order Status

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce, export, orders

I'm on Wordpress using WooCommerce, now a plugin called Parcelware allows me to export any orders between 2 dates, see the code below. I need to add to that a filter that means only 'Processing' orders are exported.

Would be great if someone can assist me!

I found this link on WooCommerce not sure if it is of any help.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/customer-order-csv-import-suite/#importingorders

```
/**
 * Read order variables from the database and store them in
 * their respective variable slot. This function is called 
 * on creation of the object.
 * 
 * @abstract
 */
abstract function read_order_settings();

/**
 * Get orders
 * 
 * @return mixed order
 */
static function get_orders( $date_from, $date_to ){
    // Get orders between the two defined dates, this function uses a filter.
    define('PARCELWARE_GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_FROM', $date_from );
    define('PARCELWARE_GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_TO', $date_to );
    add_filter('posts_where', array( __CLASS__, 'order_page_get_orders_where_dates_between') );
    $orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'offset' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'suppress_filters' => false
    ) );
    remove_filter('posts_where', 'order_page_get_orders_where_dates_between');

    return $orders;
}

/**
 * Applies a where clause on the get_posts call
 * 
 * @param string $where
 * @return string $where
 */
static function order_page_get_orders_where_dates_between( $where ){
    global $wpdb;

    if( ! defined('PARCELWARE_GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_FROM') || ! defined('PARCELWARE_GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_TO') )
        return $where;

    $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND post_date >= '%s' ", PARCELWARE_GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_FROM);
    $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND post_date <= '%s' ", PARCELWARE_GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_TO);

    return $where;
}

/**
 * Builds the header row for the csv file
 * 
 * @return string $csv
 */
static function get_csv_header(){
    return implode( self::$separator, array_keys( self::$variable_keys ) );
}

/**
 * Converts this object to a comma separated values line
 * 
 * @param mixed array $array
 * @return string $csv_line
 */
function to_CSV(){
    if( empty( $this->variables ) )
        return '';

    $csv = '';
    foreach( $this->variables as $variable )
        $csv .= $variable . self::$separator;

    return implode( self::$separator, $this->variables );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Order statuses are a taxonomy, so the following should filter that for you:

```
static function get_orders( $date_from, $date_to ){
    // Get orders between the two defined dates, this function uses a filter.
    define('PARCELWARE_GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_FROM', $date_from );
    define('PARCELWARE_GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_TO', $date_to );
    add_filter('posts_where', array( __CLASS__, 'order_page_get_orders_where_dates_between') );
    $orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'offset' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'suppress_filters' => false,
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'shop_order_status',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array('processing')
                )
            )
    ) );
    remove_filter('posts_where', 'order_page_get_orders_where_dates_between');

    return $orders;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately it still exports all orders between them dates.