# Get orders by date and status woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need get a list of orders in woocommerce passing start date, final date and status.

I tryed use some techniques like described by [Mike Jolley](http://develop.woothemes.com/woocommerce/2014/08/wc-2-2-order-statuses-plugin-compatibility/), and I mixed with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933994/how-to-filter-by-order-status). But I have not had success. This return all orders. I´m using the woocommerce version 2.2.10.

Thanks for help.

My code:

```
public function get_orders(){
        global $json_api;
        $initial_date = $json_api->query->para1;
        $final_date = $json_api->query->para2;
        $order_id = $json_api->query->para3;
        $status_order = $json_api->query->para4;

        define('GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_FROM', $initial_date );
        define('GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_TO', $final_date );
        add_filter('posts_where', array( __CLASS__, 'get_orders_where_dates_between') );
        $orders = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order'     => 'DESC',
            'post_status' => array_keys( $status_order )
        ) );
        remove_filter('posts_where', 'order_page_get_orders_where_dates_between');

        return $orders;
}

function get_orders_where_dates_between( $where ){
        global $wpdb;
        if( ! defined('GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_FROM') || ! defined('PARCELWARE_GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_TO') )
            return $where;

        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND post_date >= '%s' ", GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_FROM);
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND post_date <= '%s' ", GET_ORDERS_FILTER_DATE_TO);

        return $where;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use wc_get_orders

```
$initial_date = yyyy-mm-dd;
$final_date = yyyy-mm-dd;
$orders = wc_get_orders(array(
    'limit'=>-1,
    'type'=> 'shop_order',
    'status'=> array( 'wc-completed','wc-refunded' ),
    'date_created'=> $initial_date .'...'. $final_date 
    )
);
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query, the use of this interface is the preferred method.

Comment: Works great but it was missing colons for the dates. `$initial_date = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
$final_date = 'yyyy-mm-dd';`

Answer (score 13):

How about using custom `wpdb` query like this?

```
global $wpdb;

$date_from = '2015-11-20';
$date_to = '2015-12-20';
$post_status = implode("','", array('wc-processing', 'wc-completed') );

$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts 
            WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
            AND post_status IN ('{$post_status}')
            AND post_date BETWEEN '{$date_from}  00:00:00' AND '{$date_to} 23:59:59'
        ");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I prefer your solution since wc_get_orders seems very buggy when searching for a date range (github tickets about it plus my direct bad experience).

Comment: I'm afraid this approach is not HPOS safe, so if you use it in a plugin used in multiple stores, it won't work. This is because the table and columns are different if this setting (which is the default in newer versions) is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **timestamps** (date **AND** time):

```
$timestamp_start = '2022-04-07 20:00:00.000'; // example
$timestamp_end   = '2022-04-21 20:00:01.000'; // example
'date_created' => strtotime($timestamp_start ) .'...'. strtotime($timestamp_end)
```